# STP - protocol id in bpdu

Tags: networking, protocols, spanning-tree, stp

The STP BPDU begins with the protocol id field and the version id. I understand that the version is the type of the STP:
0 stands for STP,
2 for RSTP
and 3 for MSTP.
So what do we really need the protocol id field for? When will it not be 0?

Answer (score 0):

0 packet identifier is for IEEE 802.1D

> When will it not be 0?

Packet identifier should be 1 in IEEE 802.1G

Comment: I can barely find any information on  IEEE 802.1G. All I found was: "A proposed standard for remote MAC bridging". Is it another anti-L2-loop protocol?

Comment: neither I haven't seen it in the wild , my point is that field is for forward compatibility